# Should question regarding explaination of an Ayah (tafsir) be asked?

Tags: discussion

Though i think that this is not well suited for the Q&A style of the site because of the diversity in nature of this topic. But on the other hand it'll benefit the users and visitors. Of course we can restrict the OP to be specific about what "exactly" is the point they want to be explained.

We are from different countries and speak different languages (Arabic, English, Persian and Urdu are among those I have seen). Surely we'll have different books/sources on topic of Tafseer (تفسیر). It will be of great benefit IMO to us if we could share and compile a collection of work of different Ulemas (علماء). And i don't think that we can find such an opportunity anywhere else.

For example:
I don't understand Persian (just an example) but if a Persian user could share what are the views of Persian Ulemas are on some Ayah, then i can compare them with mine and come to a better conclusion than just being limited to my mother tongue.

Comment: For list of Shia scholars, you can check these Wikiepdia articles: [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_marjas), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ayatollahs), [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Shi%27a_Muslim_scholars_of_Islam).

Answer (score 1):

Why not? It includes discussion about Islam, ie, discussions on the Tafsir and Quranic verses itself is well on-topic and constructive.

By 'Sharing' tafsir, how do you mean to take it in a Q&A form? How would you form the questions? Do you intent to post a question in a sense to curate all the other forms of tafsir for that particular verse? If so, it would probably never get a complete answer. But I'm not sure otherwise..

Or you could simply mention in your question that you would strictly want some tafsir excerpt from a particular book/language/type or etc.. and this could get more clear answers.

Comment: yes, this is what i meant, we can share tafsir excerpts from books by different Ulemas, written in different languages in english so that most of us can understand. This would be very much informative.

Answer (score 1):

Well i don't see anything wrong in this.

You can post for an explanation only if searching around the net give you contradictory results.

Well i had a similar problem regarding an ayah, though i asked Al Ummat to solve my problem in chat.