# Policy Discussions of Islam.SE

Tags: discussion, faq, site-policy

I have compiled a list of meta discussions regarding policies of islam.SE for easy reference.

Topic of islam.SE and basics of asking, answering, voting, reputation and badges are outlined in the [about page of islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/about)

[Help page of islam.SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) aims to help newcomers about specific questions they might have.

If one cannot find answer to a particular problem related with workings of islam.SE, a question about it should be asked in islam.SE meta site.

Following are the index of meta discussions regarding the site policies.

### Featured

- [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/why-sectarianism-is-ruining-your-site)
- [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group)
- [Please vote based on quality](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/please-vote-based-on-quality)
- [Moderation when we go public](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208/moderation-when-we-go-public)
- [Take pride in your community, and work to build a site you can be proud of](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/take-pride-in-your-community-and-work-to-build-a-site-you-can-be-proud-of)

### Scope of Islam.SE

- [Islamic politics, on topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/985/islamic-politics-on-topic)
- [Are comparative studies on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/917/are-comparative-studies-on-topic)
- [Should it be allowed to ask for religious text which are there in the books but not available over the internet?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/886/should-it-be-allowed-to-ask-for-religious-text-which-are-there-in-the-books-but)
- [Religious/spiritual healing and prescriptions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/religious-spiritual-healing-and-prescriptions)
- [(Islamic) counseling and agony-aunt](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/islamic-counseling-and-agony-aunt)
- [Should dream interpretation questions be on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/780/should-dream-interpretation-questions-be-on-topic)
- [Should we tighten our scope?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/761/should-we-tighten-our-scope)
- [What should our “off-topic” close reasons be?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/744/what-should-our-off-topic-close-reasons-be)
- [What is the community we're trying to build here?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/691/what-is-the-community-were-trying-to-build-here)
- [Should we allow questions/answers based on the previous scriptures?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/683/should-we-allow-questions-answers-based-on-the-previous-scriptures)
- [Should general questions be allowed?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/660/should-general-questions-be-allowed)
- [Should Folk Islam be on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/should-folk-islam-be-on-topic)
- [Should questions asking for translations of fatwa/articles be on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/654/should-questions-asking-for-translations-of-fatwa-articles-be-on-topic)
- [Social questions off-topic or non-constructive?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/social-questions-off-topic-or-non-constructive)
- [are questions asking about great modern muslims on topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/603/are-questions-asking-about-great-modern-muslims-on-topic)
- [Are questions asking for the reliability of a source ontopic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/are-questions-asking-for-the-reliability-of-a-source-ontopic)
- [Lives of sahaba on topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/454/lives-of-sahaba-on-topic)
- [Should melting lead question be on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/should-melting-lead-question-be-on-topic)
- [Should we allow hypothetical questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338/should-we-allow-hypothetical-questions)
- [Islamic history, on topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274/islamic-history-on-topic)
- [What is our stance on book recommendations?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-is-our-stance-on-book-recommendations)
- [Islam, Islamic countries, and Islamic law](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243/islam-islamic-countries-and-islamic-law)
- [Should question regarding explaination of an Ayah (tafsir) be asked?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226/should-question-regarding-explaination-of-an-ayah-tafsir-be-asked)
- [Islam SE: Not a Muslim Peer Support Group](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group)
- [Should we allow encyclopedic questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-we-allow-encyclopedic-questions)
- [Should we allow questions regarding the Arabic language?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-arabic-language)
- [What should our "off-topic" close reasons be?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/744/what-should-our-off-topic-close-reasons-be)

### Quality Assurance

- [Deleting unuseful comments!](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1010/deleting-unuseful-comments)
- [Please vote based on quality](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/982/please-vote-based-on-quality)
- [The copy-paste issue, revisited](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/953/the-copy-paste-issue-revisited)
- [How to improve answer quality and ensure the meet the needs of the asker?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/941/how-to-improve-answer-quality-and-ensure-the-meet-the-needs-of-the-asker)
- [What should be the grace period before a post which doesn't provide the required attribution is deleted?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/932/what-should-be-the-grace-period-before-a-post-which-doesnt-provide-the-required)
- [Should question's title have inside parenthesis the view it's looking for?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/899/should-questions-title-have-inside-parenthesis-the-view-its-looking-for)
- [Big mass of ill formatted and put posts](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/846/big-mass-of-ill-formatted-and-put-posts)
- [Bismillah or it's translation to begin the post with and And Allah Knows Best to end with](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/833/bismillah-or-its-translation-to-begin-the-post-with-and-and-allah-knows-best-to)
- [What should we do about no-effort-shown questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/829/what-should-we-do-about-no-effort-shown-questions)
- [The pseudo-plagiarisms and expert answers on Islamic rulings](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/767/the-pseudo-plagiarisms-and-expert-answers-on-islamic-rulings)
- [Are “defend yourself” style posts ever constructive?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/are-defend-yourself-style-posts-ever-constructive)
- [How should we deal with “half-answers”?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/716/how-should-we-deal-with-half-answers)
- [Should we make it a requirement that all Ahadeeth quoted should be authentic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/673/should-we-make-it-a-requirement-that-all-ahadeeth-quoted-should-be-authentic)
- [Debate questions, what should we do?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/668/debate-questions-what-should-we-do)
- [Should OP downvote an answer or just comment on the answer?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/667/should-op-downvote-an-answer-or-just-comment-on-the-answer)
- [New rule for halal-haram questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/663/new-rule-for-halal-haram-questions)
- [What should our policy about images in questions be?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-should-our-policy-about-images-in-questions-be)
- [Social questions off-topic or non-constructive?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/623/social-questions-off-topic-or-non-constructive)
- [What is the correct way of quoting references?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/600/what-is-the-correct-way-of-quoting-references)
- [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/598/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)
- [Close or Comment?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/591/close-or-comment)
- [Is quesion about Caliphet is too localized?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/566/is-quesion-about-caliphet-is-too-localized)
- [The Recommended Form of Quoting Quran](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/the-recommended-form-of-quoting-quran)
- [Using images for Quranic verses](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/420/using-images-for-quranic-verses)
- [Shouldn't our site allow embedding videos?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391/shouldnt-our-site-allow-embedding-videos)
- [“Improperly Quoted Answers will be Deleted on Sight” Proposal](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369/improperly-quoted-answers-will-be-deleted-on-sight-proposal)
- [The “useless negative” problem](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/the-useless-negative-problem)
- [What guidelines should we impose on questions to ensure quality?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298/what-guidelines-should-we-impose-on-questions-to-ensure-quality)
- [Are adab questions too open ended, or listy?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/are-adab-questions-too-open-ended-or-listy)
- [Should we allow “true muslim”?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/should-we-allow-true-muslim)
- [Should we close boring/trivial questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285/should-we-close-boring-trivial-questions)
- [What policy are we to adopt in the copy-pasted answer was self-authored?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/what-policy-are-we-to-adopt-in-the-copy-pasted-answer-was-self-authored)
- [Is it approperiate to immediately edit low-quality questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/is-it-approperiate-to-immediately-edit-low-quality-questions)
- [What kind of answers are acceptable in islam.stackexchange?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1090/what-kind-of-answers-are-acceptable-in-islam-stackexchange)
- [What policy are we to adopt in the copy-pasted answer was self-authored?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1051/what-policy-are-we-to-adopt-in-the-copy-pasted-answer-was-self-authored)
- [What should we do with too basic questions?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/what-should-we-do-with-too-basic-questions)

### Language

- [What should be done with posts that are not in English?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1028/what-should-be-done-with-posts-that-are-not-in-english)
- [non-translated Arabic quotations](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/non-translated-arabic-quotations)

### Schools of Thought

- [Should we consider closing questions that accept answers from two sects?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/should-we-consider-closing-questions-that-accept-answers-from-two-sects)
- [what to do when shia-sunni conflict arises in an answer?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/935/what-to-do-when-shia-sunni-conflict-arises-in-an-answer)
- [What is the proper way to handle questions about non-mainstream Islamic sects?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/790/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-questions-about-non-mainstream-islamic-sects)
- [If someone from X sect answers a question with X evidences, Can he include evidences of Y sect?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/if-someone-from-x-sect-answers-a-question-with-x-evidences-can-he-include-evide)
- [Possible forms of Sectarianism and biased activity](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/643/possible-forms-of-sectarianism-and-biased-activity)
- [Should questions asking for one view be asked again but for a different view?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/should-questions-asking-for-one-view-be-asked-again-but-for-a-different-view)
- [If a questions prefers answer from one school of Fiqh should answers from other schools be deleted by moderators?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/560/if-a-questions-prefers-answer-from-one-school-of-fiqh-should-answers-from-other)
- [Default sect of answers](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/550/default-sect-of-answers)
- [Ask specific question to a particular sect?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/480/ask-specific-question-to-a-particular-sect)
- [Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355/the-useless-negative-problem)
- [Are questions asked specifically to promote a certain point of view allowed?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258/are-questions-asked-specifically-to-promote-a-certain-point-of-view-allowed)

### Moderation

- [Is it acceptable for a moderator to be highly inactive?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/948/is-it-acceptable-for-a-moderator-to-be-highly-inactive)
- [Should attacking an Islamic figure be grounds for suspension?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/657/should-attacking-an-islamic-figure-be-grounds-for-suspension)
- [What to do if an edit war starts?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148/what-to-do-if-an-edit-war-starts)
- [What can I do when a moderator closes a question that I think has merit?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-can-i-do-when-a-moderator-closes-a-question-that-i-think-has-merit)
- [Can a single answer specifically written for a question of this site be spam at all?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/can-a-single-answer-specifically-written-for-a-question-of-this-site-be-spam-at)

### Etiquette

- [Don't make assumptions about the beliefs of any user by just reading the post they author](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/dont-make-assumptions-about-the-beliefs-of-any-user-by-just-reading-the-post-th)

Comment: Amazing job! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. But is not it better to the meta QAs be summarized in one sentence and be added to help center as a clear policy of site. Reading too many unclear meta QAs is difficult for learning policies of site. Also meta QAs can be interpreted in different ways.

If policies only can be found in too many long meta QAs then each user needs an attorney for deciding if his post is legal or not. Each meta QA itself is too long too read. The above QA list itself is too long to read.

Do you really expect to users study so many long pages? It is like obtaining a PhD in law and so many users will prefer to simply leave the site and use other similar website. Specially Islamic experts who this site has lack of them and needs their participation.

Comment: I agree that summarizing site policies somewhere is a good idea. Purpose of this post was not to list current site policies. I collected them so it is easy for interested parties to easily find previous meta discussions regarding any topic.

Comment: @yasar11732, I see, but I want mods to also consider creating a constitution like written form of rules accepted by them or in meta QAs so that everyone can easily read and know how to act here!

Comment: @Bludream If you want some sort of "constitution", feel free to try drafting one.  That is not and has never been a moderator responsibility, so just expecting us to do it for you doesn't achieve anything.

Comment: @goldPseudo, no! I didn't mean it's your responsibility, but since mods are not acting the way unclear for others, like exactly what are all mods actions judged upon?? So I thought it's a good **recommendation** for mods here to let others also know how to act!

Comment: @goldPseudo, But after all even if the drafting process is the hard part, I guess I can do it!

Comment: @goldPseudo, only moderators can edit those pages. It is not a constitution, but it is part of requirements for a site to graduate to have a well-written help page (used to be called faq). It should contain the important policy and commonly referred policy items. Have a look at the help pages for [Christianity.se] and [Judaism.se].