# What can I do when a moderator closes a question that I think has merit?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13221/do-the-caliphs-have-the-right-to-alter-an-islamic-ruling-established-by-the-holy) was closed by a moderator. The reason given was "Unclear what you're asking", however I did attempt to edit it to improve the clarity and yet it was still closed!

Given that the question has been revised (and even answered!) I feel that closing was unnecessary. What can I do to seek redress?

Comment: Actually mod votes is binding so a mod thought it was unclear therefore the question got closed. The question here is not solely why the mod took the action it's whether the question is really unclear? Should it be reopened? That question would be more community engaging. I suggest you change the question in that direction. It wasn't the sole decision of a mod anyway, it had 3 close votes. Comments are 2nd class citizens on SE and ephemeral.

Comment: Upvotes are based on the Quality of an answer. Although the question wasn't clear, the answer answered all parts of the question with references too.

Comment: Some loitering around SE ([meta.se] etc) is required to get into the grove of SE and how things work around here. Definitely requires time and learning (but beware its [addictive](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/18372/9316)). We have the [reversal badge](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal) too.

Comment: @BleedingFingers, but aren't the mods obligated to provide explanation in case of objection by users? So far we have absolutely *no clue* as to why the question was deemed unclear! It was very clear from the beginning what the OP was asking! And it's not the question of the number of close votes either, it's whether there's any valid reason for them, especially after the edits and inquiring moderator's explanation! The silence and negative votes so far indicate that the mod and the users feel incapable of justifying their decision! But still let's keep waiting for a possible explanation.

Comment: @Sohaeb, yes, I did like your answer which is not an unrivaled opinion, though. But the very fact that you could perfectly understand and answer the question, is a testimony that the question was quite *clear*!

Comment: No, they are not obligated to, neither is any user but the community could choose to answer. This small [stretch of discussion here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15127994#15127994) might be helpful give some insight. [Mod's response.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15791961#15791961). The question can be reopened, it's not locked, only if the community chooses to and effectively overturning the close-dom. Meta discussions are helpful in resolving issues if you ask the [right question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4453/54608).

Comment: @BleedingFingers
That stretch of discussion there was indeed educative. But I still find the mod's decision for the question unjustified and I did express my objection in the chat exchange as well.

Comment: See that is my point. It's better to ask whether a question is suitable? What should be done about it? Should it be closed? Is it close worthy? etc. That way you could self-answer the question providing a cogent/convincing answer. And hence the point of meta. (It surely requires a lot of mental notes to provide an apt link at the right time. But it does pay off for the collective good.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several things you can *and should* do when you encounter a closed question you think should be re-opened:

1. **Edit it.** You may think it is perfectly good in its current state, but if there is *anything* you can do to improve the clarity, **then do it!** Try to put yourself in the place of a 3rd-party reader, and see the question through their eyes - is there anything that is ambiguous? Overly-broad or unfocused? Some often-overlooked areas for improvement are titles and tags: make sure both are clear, detailed, focused and descriptive of *the actual problem to be solved.*
2. **Vote to reopen.** If you have [the privilege to do so](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), a vote to reopen puts the question on the path to being reopened. 4 other votes are required to complete the job, but a single vote will add the question to [review](https://islam.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where others may then find it.
3. **Raise a discussion here on meta.** Tag it [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) [closed-questions](/questions/tagged/closed-questions) [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question), and state your rationale for wanting the question reopened **calmly and clearly.** If you make a good case, the community may agree to help re-open the question.

You *should* do at least one of these three, and in some cases you may wish to do *all* of them. However, having observed what you *did* do, I feel the need to also state what *not* to do:

- **DO NOT attack the folks who closed the question.** It's fine to disagree with others over a matter of policy or perception, but quite another to assume that they acted maliciously. [**Always strive to assume good faith**](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/take-pride-in-your-community-and-work-to-build-a-site-you-can-be-proud-of) and others will be more apt to do the same in return.
- **DO NOT rant and rage.** If you're upset, then walk away. Literally - go for a walk. Have a nice cup of tea maybe. Don't come back until you've calmed down and can express your concerns politely and constructively.
- **DO NOT be in a hurry.** It takes time for others in the community to read and review. They have other responsibilities. If you're patient, you may well see the results you're looking for - especially if you avoided the pitfalls laid out above. If you're impatient, then others are likely to take the same attitude with you - or just ignore you entirely.

There's no guarantee that any given question *will* be reopened. No matter how strongly you feel about a specific case, others may disagree. However, by taking the time to be polite, patient and constructive in your dealings with them, you at least stand a chance of encouraging them to be helpful in return. Therefore, if you care about seeing your question - and this site - continue to exist and thrive, you will heed this advice.

Comment: Another post of your's I'll take inspiration from.

Comment: @infatuated, "seemed clear to many users". according to this post you are the only one who found it clear. Also, don't forget that 3 people have already voted to close it. And then one of them backed down. Thus, the mod decided to close it.